# The "Star-Trek-2" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There's a tag I've seen a few times for Star-Trek-2, I feel this is a little unclear as there are almost two "2" films (it's also rather inconsistent).

Star Trek Into Darkness has it's own tag, can Star Trek 2 be changed to Star Trek Wrath of Khan to avoid any confusion?

Comment: Yet if *Into Darkness* would have any number, it would be 12 and definitely not 2.

Comment: @ChristianRau I do agree but playing devil's advocate 2nd of the reboot... a name removes all ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

Well there's already an into darkness tag, and star-trek-2 is all for the wrath of khan, so i'm ok with changing it to star-trek-wrath-of-khan

Comment: will that even fit >.>

Comment: @TylerShads - Only just. tag lengths are capped at 25 if I remember correctly

Comment: Now there are two tags: [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan) and [star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan); The latter is better.