# Merge [star-trek-wrath-of-khan] into [star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

In [The "Star-Trek-2" tag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/the-star-trek-2-tag) , the [star-trek-2](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2) tag was moved to [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan). However, there is another tag, [star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan) which is also used for this movie.

This is a request to merge [star-trek-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-wrath-of-khan) into [star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan) (which, IMO, is the least ambiguous choice).

Comment: It's very weird that both tag belongs to same person's question.

Comment: Done. Removed the `2` from the single existing question. Now somebody only needs to make `star-trek-2-wrath-of-khan` a synonym. Or we just let it go and decay into oblivion if not used anymore again.

Comment: @ChristianRau Synonyms can be better as it prevents the useless tag from existing ever again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Done